# Check if FTP Username and Password are correct in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I'd like to check if the provided username and password is correct before doing anything else on the FTP server.

As of now, I establish a connection via:

```
$cred = Get-Credential

$FTPlog = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$FTPlog = [system.net.ftpwebrequest][system.net.webrequest]::create($server)
$FTPlog.Credentials = $cred
```

$FTPlog | Get-Member doesn't show anything useful I could use to check if the login was successful or not.

I could probably try a directory listing and check this one for errors, but I'd prefer a solution which doesn't add unnecessary lines to the code. Are there any other options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that until you make a `Method` call, I do not believe you can gather any status from `StatusCode` or `StatusDescription`.  I would think that [PrintWorkingDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequestmethods.ftp.printworkingdirectory(v=vs.110).aspx) is the most lightweight call you can make.  Although why not just write the code you want and handle errors centrally regardless of when they happen?  If authentication fails, that will surely be the first thing you need to handle.

Comment: my idea was to use it for another script as a simple user authentication if there's no active directory available, but a connection to the internet.
But yes, seems like using PrintWorkingDirectory and writing a function for handling all errors might be the best option here. thanks